# Covert a file from mp4 to a file that HTML video tag can display

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a mp4 file and I want to display it in HTML. The problem is that it won't, not only in HTML but also in my player. In VLC I can watch the video but there is no sound. Maybe the file is corrupted?
This is the output when I run `ffmpeg -i my_file.mp4`:

```
[h264 @ 000001b4afc61880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001b4afc61880] no frame!
[h264 @ 000001b4afc61880] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 000001b4afc61880] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 000001b4afc61880] no frame!
Input #0, mpeg, from '150_2.mp4':
  Duration: 00:50:51.75, start: 13182.386222, bitrate: 983 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: pcm_alaw, 8000 Hz, mono, s16, 64 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified.
```

Can I convert this with ffmpeg to a good quality of video and audio?

Comment: Copy the video and encode the audio. `ffmpeg -i in -c:v copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

Comment: You can try to use [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) for converting as its document and player in HTML

Comment: @Gyan The video is of good quality but the audio quality is very poor. I cannot understand nothing.

Comment: The source audio is poor. `pcm_alaw` is used for very low bandwidth transmission.

Comment: @Gyan Can I convert it to a good quality?

Comment: @thanhphan I tried to play the video with jsmpeg but it always throwing a 404 error. Maybe only jsmpeg can play only ts files?

Comment: "JSMpeg only supports playback of MPEG-TS containers with the MPEG1 Video Codec and the MP2 Audio Codec." and yes, but you can convert .mp4 to .ts file easily with ffmpeg 
`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -f mpegts -codec:v mpeg1video -codec:a mp2 -b 0 out.ts`